# Why do Ethan and Julia just prefer to see each other from long distance rather than meeting each other?

Tags: mission-impossible, mission-impossible-ghost-protocol

In the last scene of *Mission Impossible: Ghost Protocol*, after Ethan tells William that Julia is alive, Ethan prefers to have a look of Julia only from the distance. While Julia after finding that Ethan is there and he is looking at her, does not prefer to meet him and they just give a smile to each other and then Julia steps into a shop leaving Ethan behind. Why do they not meet each other?

Comment: But isn't the reason they're doing this clearly stated in that last scene?

Comment: @Walt: What I remember is that, Ethan tells William that he accepted mission only after Chief of agency ensures him that he will keep it secrete from agency people that Julia is alive. And only Ethan knows that she is alive. But that doesn't hampers him from meeting her after mission is complete.

Comment: Yes, but he also says "as long as we're together, she can never be safe".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Julia waves bye to Ethan before going in to shop. Second, as far as I think, they both have chosen to stay separated for Julia's safety. Also Ethan only tells the secret to William to clear the misunderstanding, not any other member of his team. If they meet, it might have possible that MI agency or someone else might find her.

Comment: is safety could be the reason worth of living separated?

Comment: Generally we see that they die together instead of living separated or we expect that kind of ending for movie. But true love believes in scarifies and happiness of other.